# No output from if statements in some cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Create a program that asks the user for an age. It tells them their grade (9, 10, 11 or 12) based on their response

When I type in `16`, I don't get an output, but when I type in `14` or `15` I get the correct output.

```
age = (int(input("How old are you?")))


if (age == 14 or age ==15):
    print ("you are in grade 9")

if (age == 15):
    print("or")

    if (age == 15 or age == 16):
        print ("you are in grade 10")

        if (age == 16):
            print("or")

            if (age == 16 or age == 17):
                print ("you are in grade 11")

                if (age == 17):
                    print ("or")

                    if (age == 17 or age == 18):
                        print ("you are in grade 12")
```

Comment: A code dump is not a question. Please see [ask].

Comment: No. "Please look over code" is not a question. I have looked at your code; what do you want to be told about it?

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Please use correct indentation or use if else statements, because in your code see to get 16's output you have to fulfill previous conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting an output at `age = 16` because the control is entering the snippet only if `age = 14 or age = 15`. Since both these conditions are false, it never enters the if-else ladder, hence no output. What you need to do is

```
age = int(input('Enter your age : '))
if age == 14 or age == 15:
    print('You are in grade 9')
    if age == 15:
        print('or')
if age == 15 or age == 16:
    print('You are in grade 10')
    if age == 16:
        print('or')
if age == 16 or age == 17:
    print('You are in grade 11')
    if age == 17:
        print('or')
if age == 17 or age == 18:
    print('You are in grade 12')
```

It gives the correct output for all the inputs. Alternatively, you can also put out an if-else ladder for each age as

```
age = int(input('Enter your age : '))
if age == 14:
    print('You are in grade 9')
elif age == 15:
    print('You are in grade 9 or You are in grade 10')
elif age == 16:
    print('You are in grade 10 or You are in grade 11')
elif age == 17:
    print('You are in grade 11 or You are in grade 12')
elif age == 18:
    print('You are in grade 12')
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you out

```
age = (int(input("How old are you?")))


if age == 14:
    print ("you are in grade 9")

elif age == 15:
    print("you are in grade 10")

elif age == 16:
    print("you are in grade 11")

elif age == 17 or age == 18:
    print ("you are in grade 12")

else:
    print("invalid input")
```